# Laurent Series of $f(z) = \sin {\frac{1}{z}}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I am attempting to find the Laurent expansion at $z=0$  for $$f(z) = \sin {\frac{1}{z}}$$ where $z$ is a complex number. I rewrote the function as $$f(z)=\frac{ e^{iz^{-1}} - e^{-iz^{-1}}}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[i^n-(-i)^n]\frac{z^{-n}}{n!} $$
 What do I do next?

Comment: You are using two indicies ($m$ and $n$), when you should really only use one.  Do you know the Taylor series for sine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function $\sin z$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, so its holomorphic in every punctured neighbourhood of $\infty$. Laurent series of $\sin z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is
$$
\sin z = z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - \frac{z^7}{7!} + \ldots
$$
and in particular it's the Laurent series of $\sin z$ for $z=\infty$. Thus the Laurent series of $\sin z^{-1}$ for $z=0$ is
$$
\sin z^{-1} = z^{-1} - \frac{z^{-3}}{3!} + \frac{z^{-5}}{5!} - \frac{z^{-7}}{7!} + \ldots
$$