# Laurent expansion of $\sin(z)$ at infinity.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I have a doubt about the Laurent expansion of $\sin(z)$ at $z_0=\infty$.
I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564141/laurent-series-of-fz-sin-frac1z-at-z-0) the following expansion at $z_0=\infty$
\begin{equation*}
\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\;...
\end{equation*}
which is equal to the Laurent expansion of $\sin(z)$ at $z_0=0$. 
I don't know if I'm missing something but I'm a little confused, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It is an expansion in powers of $\frac{1}{z}$, and since at $z=\infty$ there is an essential singularity there are infinitely many terms (all of them) with negative exponent.

Comment: Maybe write it like this $... + \frac{1}{5!}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-5}-\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-3}+z + 0 + 0 + ...$